# Different results parsing the same date in Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, date, pyspark

We're using pyspark to parse a dataset containing date columns converted to an UTC timestamp with a code that looks like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp, to_utc_timestamp

session = (SparkSession
           .builder
           .appName('test_spark')
           .master('local[*]')
           .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
           .getOrCreate())
date_df = session.createDataFrame([{'date': '2017-10-29'}])
result_df = (date_df
             .withColumn('date', to_timestamp(col('date')))
             .withColumn('date', to_utc_timestamp(col('date'), 'Europe/Madrid')))
expected_df = session.createDataFrame([{'date': datetime(2017, 10, 29, 0, 0)}])
print("Expected")
print(expected_df.collect())
print("Result")
print(result_df.collect())
```

In Linux, this code prints (Spark logging omitted):

```
Expected
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 0, 0))]
Result
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 0, 0))]
```

In Windows 10, however, the output is:

```
Expected
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 0, 0))]
Result
[Row(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 29, 1, 0))]
```

As you can see, in Windows the date parsed have 1 hour more than the result in Linux.

I have tested this with both OpenJDK JRE and Oracle JRE (always version 8) but the result is the same.

What the hell is happening here? If I modify the year or the month of the dates, the "bug" no longer happens, looks like it only appears in 29 October of 2017, what makes this day so special?

Comment: The text of your question says 27 October but your program says 29 October.  29 October was the date at which Madrid switched from daylight saving time (CEST) back to standard time (CET) in 2017.  See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/spain/madrid and have it show the time-switch dates for the 2010-2019 period.

Comment: Lol you're right, I'm fixing the text; I'll try with the other DST days and see if they behave the same.

Comment: @ottomeister You're right, it's the change from CEST to CET where the bug happens (not the other way around), if you can add an answer about it I'll accept it.